# Passing values to Ruby Classes

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, user-interface, rubygems

I'm making a small application in visualruby and the code looks something like this:

```
class Base
    def initialize(x)
        @var = x
        @test = 0
    end

    def button1__clicked(*argv)
        Derived.new(@var).show
    end
end

class Derived < Base
    def initialize(x)
        super(x)
    end

    def show()      
        load_glade(__FILE__)
        set_glade_all()
        show_window() 
    end

def button1__clicked(*argv)
    #do something to test
    destory_window()
end

end
```

The idea here is that `Base` is a window. When I click on a button inside the `Base` window, a new `Derived` window shows up. What I want to do is change @test inside of `Derived`'s `button1_clicked` function and then return that value back to `Base` after the `Derived` window is destroyed.

Don't know if this is a more visualruby related question or a basic ruby programming concept question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a value to a class, but a value to an instance of a class, which is just an object.

What you need to do is have a link between the one and the other so that a message can be sent back from Derived to Base.

Perhaps like this:

```
class Base
  attr_accessible :test

  def initialize(x)
    @var = x
    @test = 0
  end

  def button1__clicked(*argv)
    Derived.new(@var, self).show
  end
end
```

This passes in a reference to the `Base` instance in question, and also makes the `test` attribute editable by others.

This can then be used:

```
class Derived < Base
  def initialize(x, base)
    @base = base
    super(x)
  end

  def button1__clicked(*argv)
    @base.test = 1 # or whatever new value is required
    destory_window()
  end
end
```

Capture a reference to it in `@base` and later exercise that.

Comment: for some reason, i'm getting this error `in `initialize': wrong number of arguments(2 for 0)`. It's not recognizing `Derived`'s initialize function. No idea why.

Comment: Are you sure that class is being loaded? It is defined with two arguments, both required, so seeing zero means it's probably a different implementation somewhere else.